# Passing "this" to a function in jQuery problems

Tags: javascript, jquery

sorry but couldn't find a solution for my problem so far.

I am writing a kind of an email template editor as a little task for my boss.

```
$('a, span').click(function(event){
    var editableElement = $(this);

    if($(this).is('a')){
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    if(editableElement.is('span')){
        processType(editableElement, 'simpleText', modalContent)
```

When I send the 'editableElement' variable first time, everything's fine, sends object to my function, where I open up a modal window, where there is a textarea, which if i enter text and submit it using only jQuery it will put the text from the textarea (using .val()) to my desired element, in this case a "span" element which is the 'editableElement' using .text() on it. No problem, it works for the first time. After I try to edit a second span, it constantly modifies the previous span too, with whatever I enter in to the textarea (which is cleared out completely, the problem is NOT here) I've ran a fast debug with a simple foreach on the editable element, and the problem is that for some reason it keeps adding objects to the editableElement variable everytime I send it to the function. The number of spans I try to edit, the number of objects will be in my variable all with the index of 0.

Any idea what could be the cause of this?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
As requested the whole code in one piece which I have problem with, though it was the whole code before too, I'm in an early stage of writing it, I understand that it was hard to read though, perhaps now it is properly formatted as requested.

```
$(window).load(function()
{
  var modalContent = $('#modalContent');
  modalOverlay = $('#modalOverlay');

  $('a, span').click(function(event)
  {
    var editableElement = $(this);

    if($(this).is('a'))
    {
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    if(editableElement.is('span'))
    {
        processType(editableElement, 'simpleText', modalContent)
    }
  });

  $('#codeGenButton').click(function()
  {
    var container = $('#codeContainer');

    container.empty();
    container.text(getPageHTML());
  });

  $('#modalClose').click(function()
  {
    $(this).parent().parent().animate({'opacity': '0'}, 200, 
      function(){
        $(this).css({'display': 'none'});
      });
    });
  });

function fillData(targetDomElement, modalObject)
{
  $('#modalSubmit').click(function(){
    targetDomElement.text($('#simpleTextEdit').val());
    closeModalWindow();
  });
}

function processType(targetDomElement, type, modalObject)
{
  modalObject.empty();

  if(type == 'simpleText')
  {
    modalObject.append("<p id='simpleTextEditTitle'>Text editor</p><textarea id='simpleTextEdit'></textarea>");
    getModalWindow();
    fillData(targetDomElement, modalObject);
  }
}
```

Step by step of what it should do:

First of all, the html should not be needed for this, it does not matter, and this is the whole code honestly.

1. - When you click on either an element of (span) or an element of (a) it triggers the function.
2. - It will check if it was actually a (span), or an (a) element.
3. - Currently if it is an element (a), it does nothing, not implemented yet, but if it is a (span), it will call in the processType function, which it sends the "handler?" of the element to namely "editableElement" which has been declared right after the click event, the 'simpleText' which gets send too, is just to differentiate between element types I will send to the processType function later on, and for the last, "modalConotent" is only a div container, nothing more.
4. - Once the function gets the data first, it will make sure, that the modal window gets cleared of ALL data that is inside of it, then it will append a bit of html code as you can see, in to the modal window, which pops up right after I have appended data in to it, it is literally just a 'display: block' and 'animate: opacity: 1' nothing special there.
5. - Lastly it will trigger the 'fillData' function, which will put my desired data from '#simpleTextField' which is only a (textarea) where you can write in, to my desired element 'editableElement' which is the element you have clicked at the first place, a (span) element after the submit, which is again, just a css of 'display: none' and 'opacity: 0' closes the modal window.

THE END.

Comment: I think we need to see the `processType` function.

Comment: Just post the whole thing in one piece, with proper formatting, please.

Comment: Can you maybe comment your code and explain step by step what it's meant to do?

Comment: I promise you it's super useful, you might even end up answering your won question. What I'm currently suspicious of is your fillDate function which would create a listener for the click event on `#modalSubmit` every time processType is called. And you also seem to be creating many elements with the same ids.

Comment: I do not create duplicate of any id-s, the container gets emptied by the .empty() function before appending a new one in to it.

Comment: I do have one lame way to fix it I think... But honestly, it should not be the correct way. If I foreach through 'editableElements' and always delete the first index and value from my object, the only remaining one will be the one I want, however I did not add an important information, even if I don't declare $(this) to 'editableElements' it STILL does the same problem. (meaning I will send $(this) directly to the function)

Comment: After playing around with it, it seems that indeed registering the .click on #modalsubmit has something to do with it, but I don't understand the connection, can someone explain please?

Comment: Your HTML as context would also be useful. Also look at providing a demo at http://jsfiddle.net/ or even better include a snippet in your question: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/. We don't need to whole lot, just enough to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here

```
function fillData(targetDomElement, modalObject)
{
  $('#modalSubmit').click(function(){
    targetDomElement.text($('#simpleTextEdit').val());
    closeModalWindow();
  });
}
```

Each time this function is called it adds a new click handler with the perameters at the time the handler was created. This handler is added in **addition** to the already created handlers. See a demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/r4t243vs/). After successive clicks on the `spans` notices how `fillData` is called multiple times for a single click.

To give you the best possible answer I need to know where your `modalSubmit` button is in relation to `modalContent`. Also is is `modalSubmit` dynamic or static on the page?

Here is a fairly hacky fix in the mean time using [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [off](http://api.jquery.com/off/) to bind and remove the handler respectively:

```
function fillData(targetDomElement, modalObject)
{
  $('#modalSubmit').off("click"); /*Clear Hanlders*/
    $('#modalSubmit').on("click", function(){
      console.log("fill data");
      console.log(targetDomElement);

    targetDomElement.text($('#simpleTextEdit').val());
    /*closeModalWindow(); Don't have anything for this so ignoring it*/
  });
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r4t243vs/1/)

Comment: Mmm, that is an interesting thing about handlers, people always learn something new, I would upvote it if I could, I don't have enough points hehe. Anyway for now I am using the .submit method which I written about above. The modalSubmit is there in the code, it is being appended to the modalContainer div everytime. It is static. Thank you for your time, and the new info (for me) about handlers!

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it myself by using .submit() (of course this means adding form, and an input with the type of submit) instead of .click() when I send the request to modify the element I've clicked on originally.

I don't understand though, why it did what it did when I've used the .click() trigger.